# Dynamics 365 CRM: Show/Hide in forms based on Status from different Entity

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-365

I am working in CRM and have created two new Qualify statuses for a Win. The first status is "Appointment Made" and the second is "Hardware Quoted". When you choose one of these and qualify the lead, the status of the lead is then changed to the option you selected.

In the Opportunity forms, I have a tab with a section and fields which include fields to be used if "Appointment Made" was selected and same for "Hardware Quoted".

What I need help with is the JavaScript code which I can hopefully insert into an event on the form/field properties to hide the other tab, when one was selected originally.

Here is the rough code I have been working on:

```
function showHideTabAndSection() {
    var statuscode = $("#statuscode").val();
    var showTab = false;
    var showSection = false;

    if (statuscode = 100000004) {
        showTab = true;
        showSection = true;
    }
    Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("TestTab1").setVisible(showTab);
    Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("TestTab1").sections.get("TestSection1").setVisible(showSection);
}
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that "statuscode" in the same form with "TestTab1"  or in another Form. if They were in different Forms  You must retrieve it's value.

See That: [JavaScript – OData Query](https://neilparkhurst.com/2017/04/13/javascript-odata-query/)

Comment: Yes they are in separate forms. The status code I want is from the Lead entity and the form I want the fields to hide on are in the Opportunity entity.

Comment: so you need to retrieve the value of Status Code from lead entity using OData.

Answer (score 0):

In opportunity form load, get the `originatingleadid` field value from current opportunity record & use it to retrieve the `statuscode` for controlling the tab/section visibility.

Recommend you to use [CRM REST Builder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder) & I generated this below code from there. If you are in V9 you can [use web api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/retrieve-entity-using-web-api) to do the same.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/leads(<<originatingleadid of opportunity>>)?$select=statecode,statuscode", true);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var result = JSON.parse(this.response);
            var statecode = result["statecode"];
            var statecode_formatted = result["statecode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
            var statuscode = result["statuscode"];
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say, *Appointment Made* has value 1, *Hardware Quoted* has value 2.

```
function showHideTabAndSection() {
    var statuscode = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("statuscode").getValue();
    switch (statuscode) {
        case 1:
            Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("appointMadeTab").setVisible(true);
            Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("hardwareQuotedTab").setVisible(false);
            break;
        case 2:
            Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("appointMadeTab").setVisible(false);
            Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("hardwareQuotedTab").setVisible(true);
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Bro I'm sorry to inform you that you just made a simple typo

```
if (statuscode = 100000004) {
```

As you see, the operator should be '==' not '='

I guess, that's why your code doesnt work.

To find problems like this in runtime, always add this line to your code
debugger;

this will stop code execution and debugs the code if you have Chrome's inspect element window open.